# Как исключить _ из почтового адреса в регулярном выражении перед @?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нашел в инете регулярку для поиска email, модифицировал под свои нужды:

```
/^[A-Za-z](\w+([\-\.](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))*?)*@(\w+([\.\-](?=(\w|\d))))+\w{2,6}$/
```

Но оно валидирует адреса вида:

```
aaaa__@aaaa.com
```

Как сделать, чтобы нижнее подчеркивание перед **@** валидацию не проходило?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/175375/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/7485582

Comment: `/^(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:[-._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*)?[A-Za-z0-9]@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,6}$/` - https://regex101.com/r/yRoCqk/1

Comment: `if(email.indexOf('_@') !== -1)` xd

Comment: Не издеваться над email'ом.

Answer (score 2):

Для исключения всех подчеркиваний первый `\w` надо заменить на `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

```
^[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9]+([\-\.](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))*?)*@(\w+([\.\-](?=(\w|\d))))+\w{2,6}$
```

С рекомендациями от *PotroNik* проверяется символ перед `@`

```
/^[A-Za-z](\w+([\-\.](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))*?)*[A-Za-z0-9]@(\w+([\.\-](?=(\w|\d))))+\w{2,6}$/
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/473451)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov почему это не ответ?

Comment: Добавьте пояснений о том, что именно Вы изменили в изначальном варианте автора, либо как составить такой regex. Соседний ответ в этом плане - правильный. Сейчас Ваше сообщение неверно по ФОРМЕ. На счет содержания - это уже пусть решает автор вопроса.

Comment: Не согласен. Автор не просит новое выражение, просит изменить свое. Я показал, что выдает символ подчеркивание, привел измененное выражение.

Comment: Да, виноват, изменение в Вашем варианте показалось куда более сильным, чем есть на самом деле

Comment: @AlexR. В вашем варианте исключается и `mail_mail@mail.ru` т.е. адреса где есть нижнее подчеркивание не зависимо от положения в строке, если речь идет об изменении, то проще всего заменить часть `...*?)*@...` на `....*?)*[A-Za-z0-9]@...` оставив остальное как есть

Comment: Спасибо. Да, у вас лучше. Если не будете писать свой ответ, то я бы привел полный текст выражения со ссылкой на вас.

Comment: У меня уже есть вариант ответа, вы можете внести изменения в свой ответ без ссылки на меня, это лишь рекомендация была.

Answer (score 1):

Написал такой regexp:

```
(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])^[\w-\.]+[A-Za-z0-9]@[\w-]+[A-Za-z0-9]\.([\w-]+[A-Za-z0-9]\.){0,}[A-Za-z]{2,6}$
```

Пример работы:
https://regex101.com/r/Jh8d0J/2

---

`(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])` - проверка что первый символ цифра или буква
`^` - начало строки
`[\w-\.]+` - любой буквенный символ, цифра, тире, точка и нижнее подчеркивание
`[A-Za-z0-9]@` - любо символ латинского алфавита или цифра, за которым следует символ @
`[\w-]+\.` - буквенный символ латинского алфавита, цифра, нижнее подчеркивание и тире, перед символом точки
`([\w-]+[A-Za-z0-9]\.){0,}` - для почты зарегистрированной на домене третьего и выше уровней
`[A-Za-z]{2,6}$` от 2 до 6 символов латинского алфавита

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на то, что нужно было. У меня у самого получилось такое выражение ```^[A-Za-z0-9]+(([_\.\-](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\-\.](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))*?)*@(\w+([\.\-](?=(\w|\d))))+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$``` вроде тоже работает.

Comment: @DK на данном ресурсе не запрещено отвечать на свой вопроса, можете оформить как ответ, если считаете что ваше решение наиболее подходящее.

Answer (score 0):

Чуть переделал, получилось так:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(([_\.\-](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\-\.](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))*?)*@(\w+([\.\-](?=(\w|\d))))+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```